# C# Struct array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have this project which I am working on, and I need help on C# structs. I am using a Console application.

What I'm after is to create a struct that I can use in a array. What I have so far is:

```
    public struct array
            {
                public static int id;
                public static int x;
                public static int y;
            };
    public static  array[] test = new array[amount];
```

Then what I want to be able to do is set the variables like this.

```
test[i].id = 1;
test[i].x = 1;
test[i].y = 1;
```

However it isn't working. If anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated a lot.

Thank you
Adam

Comment: Fixed the stupid syntax error, sorry. That wasnt the problem

Comment: **What error do you get**?

Comment: -1 for asking a completely bogus question, posting made up fake code, and also for describing the problem as "it isn't working". Please do try harder to ask a real question (never ever post fake code) and describe your problem properly.

Comment: It wasn't a bogus fake code. When I was writing it out I made a simple mistake. I also fixed it within the minute.

Comment: You've posted two completely different variants now. At least one of them is fake. Yes you made a simple mistake. The mistake was that you were writing the code rather than pasting it. That's how you ended up posting fake code. What's more you have still not improved on "it isn't working". You really do need to take more time and care when asking questions.

Comment: I did write the code, and I know I didn't read over my question which I should of, I did apologise and I do again, however I have it  working now, and can continue on my project. Thank you all, have a nice day. Adam

Comment: My two pieces of advice, I hope you heed them. If you do, it will be better for you. 1. Paste code into a question, never type it. 2. Always describe the error in full detail. It is never enough to say "it isn't working".

Comment: Thanks, I shall do from now on. Also the "isn't working" part is due to the IDE(Visual Studio 12) not picking up on the variables. Thanks

Comment: That's not what I mean. You said "it isn't working". But I'm quite sure that your compiler did not say that. It would have given an error message. It's that message that we need. When you say "it isn't working", there could be compiler error, runtime error, no error but behaviour that you did not expect and so on. That detail is critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the fields non-`static`.
`static` fields are associated with the type; not each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is this:

```
 array[] test = new array[amount];
        array temp = new array();

        temp.id = 1;
        temp.x = 1;
        temp.y = 1;

        test[i] = temp;
```

And remove the static.

Hope this will help you